# SQL Query to aggregate telephone numbers called and the totals

Tags: sql

I have a single database table that has telephone call records in it named call_detail_master
Each record makes up one call. the number calling is 'lineno' and the number called is 'nocalled'

I'm trying to write query to generate for each 'lineno' the number of distinct 'nocalled' where called and how many calls where made to that 'nocalled' so I can profile calling patterns

Would appreciate any suggestions

Answer (score 1):

I think this query will return what you want.

```
SELECT lineno, nocalled, count(nocalled)
FROM call_detail_master
GROUP by lineno, nocalled
```